# Can I upload a reverse shell to a website remotely if directory listing is enabled?

Tags: wordpress

Can I upload a PHP reverse shell to a WordPress website if there is a directory listing vulnerability in the website? The condition is that I can see the entire file structure of `/wp-includes` in a WordPress website and I want to upload a PHP Reverse Shell in the directory `/wp-includes` so that I can get a reverse connection.

Is it possible?

Comment: There is a big difference between "read access" and "write access"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't upload a reverse shell just because directory listing is enabled. You would need another vulnerability that allows you to upload arbitrary files to do that.